# How can I know if a property of dynamic object does not exist OR its value is null? Using NewtonSoft

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

If I access the property like this:

```
if (dynamicObject["propertyName"] == null)
```

I'll get true in 2 cases:

1. This property does not exist in this dynamic object.
2. This property exists but its value is null

When I am using Newtonsoft library, GetType() will return "JObject" And GetProperty() for "JObject" doesn't work (always return null). Therefore I couldn't use it.

```
dynamicObject.GetType().GetProperty()
```

How can I differentiate between both cases? Is there an other accurate check I can do?

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of ways to handle this; both are pretty similar.

**Option 1**

Since you already know that your dynamic object is really a `JObject`, you can cast it (or just eliminate the dynamic variable entirely and deserialize your JSON directly to a `JObject` from the get-go).  From there, you can use the same syntax to try to get the property value (a `JToken`).  If the property does not exist, the result will be null.  Otherwise, you can check the token's `Type` property to find out whether it is `JTokenType.Null` or some other token type:

```
JObject jo = (JObject)dynamicObject;
JToken token = jo["propertyName"];
if (token == null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("property does not exist.");
}
else if (token.Type == JTokenType.Null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("property exists with a value of null.");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("property exists with with a value of \"" + token.ToString() + "\".");
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/3Nrwns

**Option 2**

If you prefer to work with the dynamic object as it is, then you'll need to use `object.ReferenceEquals` to to determine whether the property exists.  If it does, then you can use a regular null check to find out whether the value is null:

```
dynamic val = dynamicObject["propertyName"];
if (object.ReferenceEquals(val, null))
{
    Console.WriteLine("property does not exist.");
}
else if (val == null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("property exists with a value of null.");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("property exists with with a value of \"" + val.ToString() + "\".");
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/4Mmbak